# Comparing two files based on 1st column, printing the unique part of one file

Tags: awk, grep, diff, comm

I have two files looking like this:

file1:

```
RYR2 29 70  0.376583106063  4.77084855376
MUC16 51 94 0.481067457376  3.9233164551
DCAF4L2 0 13    0.0691414496833 3.05307268261
USH2A 32 62 0.481792717087  2.81864194236
ZFHX4 14 37 0.371576262084  2.81030548752
```

file2:

```
A26B2
RYR2
MUC16
ACTL9
```

I need to compare them based on first column and print only those lines of first file that are not in second, so the output should be:

```
DCAF4L2 0 13    0.0691414496833 3.05307268261
USH2A 32 62 0.481792717087  2.81864194236
ZFHX4 14 37 0.371576262084  2.81030548752
```

I tried with grep:

```
 grep -vFxf file2 file1
```

with awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {exclude[$0];next} !($0 in exclude)' file 2 file1
```

comm:

```
comm -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

nothing works

Comment: `grep -vf file2 file1` works fine for me. Check your files for DOS line endings.

Comment: @Cyrus it works! thank you so much

Comment: Your awk is very close: you just want to see if the *first word* is in the array: `!($1 in exclude)` (and of course remove the space between "file" and "2" to get the right file)

Comment: For your grep command, the `-x` option is the incorrect bit here: that instructs grep to compare the whole line to the patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
grep -vFf file2 file1
```

Also, `grep -vf file2 file1` will work, too, but in case the `file2` strings contain `*` or `[` that should be read in as literal chars you might get into trouble since they should be escaped. `F` makes `grep` treat those strings as fixed strings.

**NOTES**

- `-v`: Invert match.
- `-f file`: Take regexes from a file.
- `-F`: Interpret the pattern as a list of fixed strings (instead of regular expressions), separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.

So, it reads the regexes from `file2` and applies them to `file1`, and once it finds a match, that line is not output due to inverted search. This is enough because only the first column contains alphanumerics, the rest contain numeric data only.

**Why your command did not work**

The `-x` (short for `--line-regexp`) option means *`Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line`*.

Also, see more about [`grep` options in `grep` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html).